# AWS s3 caching images by url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching

One of the functions of my app is storing images for cars in an s3 bucket. The images are categorized by their url eg: `https://{bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/{vin}/{photoCategory}.jpg`
`https://{bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/1B3EL46X95N553721/Full_Instrument_Cluster.jpg`

The user needs to be able to update images at a given url. In testing the implementation of this feature I have been able to confirm that the image is in fact being replaced in s3, however this change is not showing up in the browser even after refreshing the page. My only guess is that because the url doesn't change, the browser has cached the image from s3. I wanted to know if there was some way to get around this behavior, to prevent the browser from caching the image

```
  const uploadParams = {

    Bucket: "bucketName",

    Key: "filePath",

    Body: fileStream,

    Metadata: {
      Cache: "no-cache"
    }

  };

  const s3Data = await client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
```

Comment: just for you or for everyone that visits the page?

Comment: @WillBrobin It's running locally right now. The answer below is on the right track but we need to figure out how to do things programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is if you don't have any other caching layer (CDN, service worker, etc) in your setup to set the `Cache-Control` of the S3 object to `no-cahe` like the following way.

Go to the object -> Select `Edit Metadata` -> add the `header/metadata`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is the fix! One last thing, the photo is being uploaded programmatically via the javascript sdk. Do you know how to add this header with the javascript sdk as the photo is being uploaded? It seems like you can add a field for metadata like so but I'm not sure how to add no-cache properly. I added my upload params to the op so you can see what I have so far

Comment: I fixed it, check the op